# gcc compile errors in an basic example objc program

Tags: objective-c, gcc

Hey all, I'm new to programming and going through an objective-c book to learn the language and programing fundamentals. I've looked through the code repeatedly, went back to the book's example, and attempted to understand the gcc comple errors. Here's my code:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>

@interface Point: Object
    {
        int xaxis;
        int yaxis;
    }

    -(void) print;
    -(void) setx:   (int)x;
    -(void) sety:   (int)y;

@end

@implementation Point;

    -(void) print
        {
            printf("(%i,%i)", xaxis, yaxis);
        }

    -(void) setx:   (int) x
        {
            xaxis = x;
        }

    -(void) sety:   (int) y
        {
            yaxis = y;
        }
@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Point *myPoint;

        myPoint = [Point alloc];

        myPoint = [myPoint init];

        [myPoint setx: 4];
        [myPoint sety: 5];

        printf("The coordinates are: ");
            [myPoint print];
        printf("\n");

        [myPoint free];

        return 0;

    }
```

Then the compile errors from gcc look like this:

```
urban:Desktop alex$ gcc point.m -o point -l objc
point.m: In function ‘main’:
point.m:38: warning: ‘Point’ may not respond to ‘+alloc’
point.m:38: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
point.m:38: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept
point.m:38: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)
point.m:40: error: ‘mypoint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
point.m:40: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
point.m:40: error: for each function it appears in.)
point.m:49: warning: ‘Point’ may not respond to ‘-free’
```

Where am I going wrong?

btw I'm going through "Programming in Objective-C" by Stephen Kochan if you wanted to know.

Comment: In which platform are you compiling your program?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X. 10.6

Comment: In that case, it’s best to use `NSObject` instead of `Object` since the stock compilers on Mac OS X use Objective-C 2.0, which won’t build `Object` as a fully functional root class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have warnings and an error. The warnings seem to suggest that `Object`, which you are subclassing, doesn't implement `alloc`, `init` or `free`. Normally, on an Apple platform, you'd subclass `NSObject`, which does implement these, but without knowing which platform you're on, it's not possible to advise the correct option.

Secondly, you had a typo, but that now seems to be corrected. This

```
point.m:40: error: ‘mypoint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

suggests that you had `mypoint` in your code, rather than `myPoint`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I corrected the typo, initialized and allocated the object in the same statement (`Point *myPoint = [[Point alloc] init];`) changed the subclass to NSObject and switched `<objc/Object.h>` to `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`. And yes, I'm on a Mac. When I compile I get `point.m:6: error: ‘Point’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h:501: error: previous declaration of ‘Point’
point.m:9: error: redefinition of ‘struct Point’` and when I attempt to run the program:

Comment: `urban:Desktop alex$ ./point
objc[60472]: Point: Does not recognize selector forward::
Illegal instruction
urban:Desktop alex$ `

Comment: @imgeekboy The problem with using Apple’s frameworks is that `Point` is already declared as a `struct` in Carbon. Rename your `Point` class to something else, e.g. `MyPoint`, and your code should compile and run just fine.

Answer (score 2):

First the base class should be NSObject, not Object

the normal way to do the initialization is to write the alloc and init in the same statement. You would typically have an -(id)init; method in your class:

```
-(id)init
{
  if ( ( self = [super init] ) )
  {
    ; // additional initialization goes here
  }
  return self;
}
```

and

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Point *myPoint = [[Point alloc] init];
```

Properties are better used, then you get the setter and getter automatically generated for you

instead of

```
@interface Point: Object
    {
        int xaxis;
        int yaxis;
    }
```

write

```
@interface Point : NSObject
{
}

@property int xaxis;
@property int yaxis;
```

then when you assign you can either write

```
[myPoint setXaxis:4]
```

or

```
myPoint.xaxis = 4;
```

when you release the object write release, not free

```
[myPoint release];
```

hth

Comment: Depending on the runtime, `Object` is a valid root class.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the header Foundation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```